# Make area around masked region transparent with CALayers?

Tags: objective-c, transparency, calayer, mask

I'm trying to crop an image to an irregular shape, but I need to make the area that was removed transparent.

Inside subclass of UIView

```
   CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
   CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];    
    myLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    myLayer.contents =  (id)[self.picture CGImage];
    mask.path = path;
    myLayer.mask = mask;
    [self.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

This will crop the image appropriately, but the background color of the view is white and therefore still visible. I've tried making the other layers transparent, but it has not worked.

(self and subview both refer to same view)

```
[self layer].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor //no change
[self layer].opacity = 0; //makes entire view transparent
subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // entire view becomes transparent
```

Is it possible to create the effect I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same thing, here is the exact code:

```
// In KMViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    KMView *view = [[KMView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    view.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}

// In KMView.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.frame = self.bounds;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange"];
        layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
        CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(frame, NULL);
        mask.path = path;
        CGPathRelease(path);
        layer.mask = mask;
        [self.layer addSublayer:layer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It worked for me as expected. The background was transparent. Then I tried adding

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to the beginning of the code and nothing changed, the image was showing on a transparent background clipped to the path.

I think the problem might be somewhere else.

[image: iPhone]

Comment: Is there any difference between putting the logic in init vs drawrect? Mine is in drawrect; that's the only difference I currently see.

Comment: I would test myself, but I don't currently have access to my code

Comment: This code should not be in `drawRect:`. `drawRect:` is meant for Core Graphics drawing code like CGPath's etc. Put the code in `initWithFrame:` and see if it works.

Comment: An excerpt from the documentation of `drawRect:`, emphasis mine. "The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses that use native drawing technologies (such as Core Graphics and UIKit) to draw their view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing code there. **You do not need to override this method if your view sets its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override this method if your view just displays a background color or if your view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object.**"